# Tem como aceitar virgula e ponto para float em C?

Tags: c, c++, float, decimal

Eu gostaria de fazer um programa extremamente simples, porém tem um problema que gostaria de resolver. Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    float num;

    printf("Insira metros para converter para cm): \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%f", &num);

    printf("%.2f\n", num*100);

system("pause");
}
```

Se eu não adicionar a biblioteca locale.h, para o usuário digitar um número decimal ele terá que separar com ponto (.), e se eu adicionar ele terá que separar com vírgula (,). Tem alguma forma do meu programa aceitar tanto vírgula quanto ponto para separar decimais?

Obrigado.

Comment: Lês o input como string, trocas (se existir) as virgulas por pontos, depois convertes a string (com pontos) em valor de virgula flutuante.

Comment: Vc pode me indicar algo que me ensine isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes ler o input como string, trocar (se existir) as virgulas por pontos, depois converter a string (com pontos) em valor de virgula flutuante

```
#include <stdlib.h> // strtod
#include <string.h> // strchr
double texttodouble(const char *p) {
    char *v = strchr(p, ','); // encontra a primeira virgula
    if (v) *v = '.';          // substitui por ponto
    return strtod(p, NULL);   // devolve double, assume locale "C"
}
```

Ver https://ideone.com/A2DpPC

Nota que este código (e o que está no ideone) não tem validação de erros, e que isso é necessário para um bom programa.

Answer (score 1):

O jeito "certo" é usar um recurso chamado "locale".

Exemplo:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float num;

  setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "pt_BR");

  printf("Insira metros para converter para cm: ");
  scanf("%f", &num);

  printf("%.2f\n", num);

  getchar();
}
```

Rodando no Linux:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$ ./so373270 
Insira metros para converter para cm: 2,54
2,54...

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

Para funcionar no Windows parece que o locale é "pt-BR" e não "pt_BR" como usei acima, mas eu não testei.